# How do I look for text in saved search?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm beginning in suitescirpt and I have the following code:

```
filters[i++] = search.createFilter({
                name: 'custrecord_l595_numerad_tipo_transaccion',
                operator: search.Operator.IS,
                values: tipoTrans
            });
```

`tipoTrans` returns a text like: 'invoice', and I want to make a search in a record type, but it requires a numeric value, in the record type it shows itself as text, but seems like is looking for internalid, I would like to know the way i can look for the text in the field, and not for the internalID

Comment: Tell me if I understand this correctly: you have a custom field 'custrecord_l595_numerad_tipo_transaccion' that contains a record type, which you are using as a criteria in your search? What is the Type of this field?

Comment: What is the populated in "custrecord_l595_numerad_tipo_transaccion"? Is it a specific transaction? Is it a list of transaction types? If it is a list is it a native or custom list? 
A bit hard to give a specific answer without this information about the field you are searching on.
That being said in general you can use a formula text to match text values. Not always the best way to do what you are doing but it's one way to match text.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this as follows: I made a simple search apart pointed to a list who has the internal id and the name that is returned. In that way, I could get what I needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).